# Highcharts : How to align column chart and bubble chart vertically in the same series

Tags: javascript, html, css, highcharts

As shown in this image, i have this requirement of aligning column chart and a bubble chart on a single series. But when i do this there is a small mismatch in column sizes of charts. Any body know a direct solution or a work around for this? Help would be greatly appreciated.

[image: image: <code>http://i.imgur.com/4twx0EF</code>]

Comment: Off the cuff guess, your yaxis is a different size.  Top is in the 100s (three numbers), bottom is in the 10s (two numbers).  If you want more help, show some code or better yet reproduce the problem in a jsFiddle...

Comment: Hi Mark, As you said Y values will be different, but the X-axis values and the range is exactly same for two charts. Bubble size can be adjusted by a factor. Find the sample fiddle here. http://jsfiddle.net/aravindal/UkS74/

Comment: y axis scaling itself shouldn't have any effect, although the left margin created for the labels will - set your left margin for each chart explicitly.  Beyond that, it is a matter of how spacing is laid out for columns.  Some playing around with minPadding and maxPadding settings may get you what you need...?

Comment: some small amount of luck per my last post, though it is rather clumsy:  http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/fQ69x/

Comment: @jlbriggs, I was referring to the yaxis spacing, not the values (hence the 3 numbers - wider vs 2 numbers - narrower).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using to separated chart, you can use single with two yAxis panes.

```
series:[{
    type:'column',
    data:[2,3,5,8,15,12,7,4]
}, {
    yAxis:1,
    type:'bubble',
    data:[2,3,5,8,15,12,7,4]
}]
```

EDIT:
http://jsfiddle.net/fQ69x/4/

Comment: @ Sebastian, I have tried as your example and was able to generate the chart for a certain extend. I need to show two different tool tips in two charts, but it is not formatting when i put the tool tip options under series, and what is the exact relationship between top and height parameters.

Comment: Yah. I have used similar approach to differentiate two types of charts for generating tool tip. And i was able to generate two types of charts in the same div as much as possibly aligned with the requirement. Help is appreciated.